# транзакция выполняется частично

Tags: mysql, sql, транзакции

господа, прошу объяснить элементарное

```
## mysql, innoDB

START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE `users` SET `bill`=(`bill`-4500) WHERE `id`='7';
UPDATE `users` SET `bill`=(`bill`+4500) WHERE `id`='5';
COMMIT;
```

Изучаю транзакции. Пытаюсь с одного пользователя списать деньги, а другому записать. Данная конструкция работает, но, ест-но охота проверить, что если ошибка? Удаляю пользователя 7. Транзакция Все равно записывает деньги пользователю 5. Если же дописать пользователю 7 в UPDATE условие

```
... WHERE `id`='7' AND `bill`>='4500';
```

первый запрос - не происходит ничего, второй ест-но выполняется

собственно, подскажите, как изменить запрос, что бы при второй запрос выполнялся только если выполнен первый?

Comment: Объедините запросы. *что бы при второй запрос выполнялся только если выполнен первый?* Может, имеется в виду - если первым запросом значение обновлено? А то, знаете ли, если нет записи с id=7, первый запрос-то всё одно выполнится - только ничего не обновит.

Comment: *Транзакция Все равно записывает деньги пользователю 5.* Правильно. Ошибки выполнения-то не было... вот если бы сработал какой-нить `CHECK (bill >=0)` - тогда другое дело.

Comment: тогда как сделать, проверку на то, что списание было? я так понял я не корректно задал вопрос ((

Comment: Чего спрашивать? просто см. ответ Антона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А первый запрос у вас выполняется. Другой вопрос, что он обновляет 0 записей. Чтобы узнать число записей, затронутых предыдущим запросом есть функция `ROW_COUNT()`

По идее, вот так будет работать

```sql
UPDATE `users` SET
  `bill`= `bill` + 4500
WHERE
  `id`='5' AND
  ROW_COUNT() > 0;
```

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать 2 запроса, и съэмитировать, что с одним проблема, по этому последовательно выполнять не вариант. т.е. или списываем/записываем деньги с 2х счетов, или откат

Comment: @sergey Я так и понял. Замените свой второй UPDATE на мой